# Oracle Apex 5 Data Loader

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5

I have created a data loader for my application on Oracle APEX 5 and it works.
However, the default behavior isn't suitable for my case.

What it does is :

- insert all valid new rows (Inserted Row(s))
- update all valid existing rows (Updated Row(s))
- reject all invalid rows (Failed Row(s))
- i don't even know (To be Reviewed Row(s))

What I would like it to do :

- Either all rows are valid, in that case we insert them all
- Or one of the rows is invalid, in that case, we insert **nothing**

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Can you explain exactly how you built the data loader?  There are lots of different ways to accomplish that task.  Posting code is always helpful.  As it stands, we can tell you that you'll need to modify the code you wrote but not knowing what you wrote, it's hard to guess how to modify it.

Comment: @JustinCave, I didn't write any code, I used the wizard. App > Create Page > Page type : Data Loading.

Comment: I haven't used the data loader page type myself, but I'd imagine it "does what it does".  So perhaps you could make it load into a staging table first where there are no existing rows or constraints that might fail, then write your own process to move the data into the real table according to your business logic.

Comment: just use exception handling...